# Keras：load_model ValueError: axes don't match array

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm studying gan with [keras-gan/wgan-gp](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/tree/master/wgan_gp) example with my own dataset. I save models with
`wgan.generator.save('generator.h5')`

`wgan.critic.save('critic.h5')`

and load with

`model = load_model('generator.h5')`

`model = load_model('critic.h5')`

But this only works fine at the fist time.When I saved the models again after the second training and run

`model = load_model('generator.h5')`

`model = load_model('critic.h5')`

again, the error occur ：

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 model = load_model('generator.h5')
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
>       262 
>       263         # set weights
>   --> 264         load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
>       265 
>       266         if compile:
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers, reshape)
>       914                                                        original_keras_version,
>       915                                                        original_backend,
>   --> 916                                                        reshape=reshape)
>       917         if len(weight_values) != len(symbolic_weights):
>       918             raise ValueError('Layer #' + str(k) +
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
>       555         weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
>       556     elif layer.**class**.**name** in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
>   --> 557         weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
>       558 
>       559     if original_keras_version == '1':
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in convert_nested_model(weights)
>       543                     weights=weights[:num_weights],
>       544                     original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
>   --> 545                     original_backend=original_backend))
>       546                 weights = weights[num_weights:]
>       547         return new_weights
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
>       555         weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
>       556     elif layer.**class**.**name** in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
>   --> 557         weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
>       558 
>       559     if original_keras_version == '1':
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in convert_nested_model(weights)
>       531                     weights=weights[:num_weights],
>       532                     original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
>   --> 533                     original_backend=original_backend))
>       534                 weights = weights[num_weights:]
>       535
>
> D:\keras\engine\saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
>       673             weights[0] = np.reshape(weights[0], layer_weights_shape)
>       674         elif layer_weights_shape != weights[0].shape:
>   --> 675             weights[0] = np.transpose(weights[0], (3, 2, 0, 1))
>       676             if layer.**class**.**name** == 'ConvLSTM2D':
>       677                 weights[1](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/tree/master/wgan_gp) = np.transpose(weights[1](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/tree/master/wgan_gp), (3, 2, 0, 1))
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in transpose(a, axes)
>       596 
>       597     """
>   --> 598     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
>       599 
>       600
>
> c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>        49 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
>        50     try:
>   ---> 51         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
>        52 
>        53     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have
>
> ValueError: axes don't match array`

I'm using

`Python     3.5.3`

`Keras      2.2.2`

`h5py       2.8.0`

`tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0`

`keras-contrib  2.0.8`

`Keras-Applications   1.0.4`

`Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.2`

Any advice and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like the issue described in:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11847

and

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27769

While the bug has yet to be fixed, the problem only occurs when there are both trainable and non-trainable weights in the model.  If you do not need to train the model further, you can work around the problem by freezing all the weights prior to saving:

```
from keras import models

def freeze(model):
    """Freeze model weights in every layer."""
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

        if isinstance(layer, models.Model):
            freeze(layer)
```

Comment: I get the following error with tf 1.3.0 and keras 2.4 when I run model.predict() after saving

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable final_output/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/final_output/bias)
  [[{{node final_output/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]
  [[{{node final_output/Sigmoid}}]]`

Any resolution?

Comment: Had the same issue with `axes don't match array` when trying `model.load_weights()`. Fixed the problem with `model.trainable = True`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `trainable = False` dint worked for me
This worked for me : As i have set `trainable = True`

```
from keras import models
def freeze(model):
    """Freeze model weights in every layer."""
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = True

        if isinstance(layer, models.Model):
            freeze(layer)
    model.save("./model.h5")    

model = models.load_model("./model.h5")
freeze(model)
```

Now this saved model was error free
And then i could do all operation like `save_weights`, `load_weights` etc

Note: Do these all exp on same `envs` or same `keras/tf` version where your model was first saved

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the keras version to 2.1.5. It solved the problem for me.

Comment: I have the same error even after downgrading to 2.1.5. I can load old weights but not the currently trained weights.

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing training and prediction on the same machine?
Changing tensorflow's versions to be the same for both training and prediction machines solved the issue for me